# Error: 'list' object is not calllable

Tags: python, list, calculator

Every time I run this script and input some numbers it appears with the error ***'list' object is not callable"*** How do I fix this? (I'm relatively new to programming)

```
numbers=[0]      ←←←←←ERROR HERE
operations=[0]
number=1
result=0
iteration=1
user_input=0
while not user_input=="done" :
    if not user_input=="done":
        user_input=input("Number"+str(number))
        numbers.append(float(user_input))
        user_input=input("Operation")
        operations.append(str(user_input))
        number+=1
while iteration<=len(numbers):
    if operations(iteration-1)=="+":
        result+=numbers[iteration-1]
    elif operations(iteration-1)=="-":
        result-=numbers[iteration-1]
print("The answer is "+str(result))
```

Comment: I think your error is actuality referring to `operations(iteration-1)`

Comment: Please notice how you access the `numbers` list. Do the same for the `operations` list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `operations` in here `operations(iteration-1)=="+":` and in here `operations(iteration-1)=="-":`.

Did you mean to index the list? If so use `[]`.